# How to convert array of strings into array of struct with conditions

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with single column `_c0`.

```
a|b|c|clm4=1|clm5=3
a|b|c|clm4=9|clm6=60|clm7=23
```

I am trying to convert it to a dataframe of selected columns like this

```
clm1,clm2,clm3,clm4,clm6,clm7,clm8
a,    b,   c,   1,  null,null,null
a,    b,   c,   9,   60,  23, null
```

Please note that I removed `clm5` and added `clm8`.

I am using below code:

```
transform_expr = """
    transform(split(_c0, '[|]'), (x, i) -> 
                       struct(
                             IF(x like '%=%', substring_index(x, '=', 1), concat('_c0', i+1)), 
                             substring_index(x, '=', -1)
                             )
            )
    """
    
    
    df = df.select("_c0",  explode(map_from_entries(expr(transform_expr))).alias("col_name", "col_value")).groupby("_c0").pivot('col_name').agg(first('col_value')).drop("_c0")
```

The problem is that I have multiple huge files on which I want to perform this action and the result of each file should contain same columns(which is also a long list) which can have null values if not present in input file. How can I add a condition to the above code to select only those column which are present in a list of column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the desired columns in a list and use it to filter the transformed array :

```
column_list = ["clm1", "clm2", "clm3", "clm4", "clm6", "clm7", "clm8"]
```

Now add this filter after the transform step using [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#filter) function:

```
column_filter = ','.join(f"'{c}'" for c in column_list)

transform_expr = f"""
            filter(transform(split(_c0, '[|]'), (x, i) -> 
                               struct(
                                     IF(x like '%=%', substring_index(x, '=', 1), concat('clm', i+1)) as name, 
                                     substring_index(x, '=', -1) as value
                                     )
                    ), x -> x.name in ({column_filter}))
            """
```

This will filter out all the columns that are not present in the list.

And finally, add the missing columns as nulls using simple select expression:

```
df = df.select("_c0",  explode(map_from_entries(expr(transform_expr))).alias("col_name", "col_value")).groupby("_c0").pivot('col_name').agg(first('col_value')).drop("_c0")

## add missing columns as nulls
final_columns = [col(c).alias(c) if c in df.columns else lit(None).alias(c) for c in column_list]

df.select(*final_columns).show()

#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
#|clm1|clm2|clm3|clm4|clm6|clm7|clm8|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
#|   a|   b|   c|   9|  60|  23|null|
#|   a|   b|   c|   1|null|null|null|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. this seems advanced. I am searching for these methods for many days to understand them better but didn't find anything. Can you suggest any platform where i can gain more knowledge about these on how these work?

Comment: You can find many articles about higher-order functions like Databricks : [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html) or [here](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html) or [others](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/apache-spark-2.4.0-features-array-higher-order-functions/read)

Comment: Thanks.. i just tried above solution but I am using above code inside a method which I am calling using pool.apply_async() method for multiprocessing as the data is huge. and The stage it encounters loop it exits without completing.